# Offset with a cell value

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I'm trying to do an IF formula that compares the value of an offset cell

```
leadtime_value2 = Range("H3").Value
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF('ActiveCell.Offset(leadtime_value2,-1)'=TRUE,F7-C8+$D$1,F7-C8)"
```

As you can see I'm telling my that my cell to compare is the one the number of times Cell H3 value up in rows (Because H3 is negative) and one column left in the active cell value

H3 value is an input from the user

Could you please tell me the proper syntax for this code?

Comment: ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(Offset(" & leadtime_value2 & ",-1)=TRUE,F7-C8+$D$1,F7-C8)" I think..

Comment: `ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(" & ActiveCell.Offset(leadtime_value2,-1).Address & "=TRUE,F7-C8+$D$1,F7-C8)"`

Comment: It works but it fixes the cell, I mean it references like this $C$8. How do you delete the $ $?

Comment: add the extra properties to the address() or try without, mine above

Comment: oh... sorry: `.Address(false,false)` will do it (or if you want it short: `.Address(0,0)`